# Free solution for tracking mac kext installs - managing security with disabled kext-signing

Tags: security, ssd, osx-yosemite, security-warning, kext

The goal is to track when kexts are installed and determine whence kexts came. For instance TRIM is disabled for 3rd party drives in OS X Yosemite. To use a utility like Trim Enabler one must disable kext signing globally. WRT to http://www.cindori.org/trim-enabler-and-yosemite/ – specifically:

“It is important to note that the kext-signing setting is global, if you disable it you should be careful to only install system drivers from sources that you trust.”

It occurs this would be a manageable security issue if one can track kext installed when kext signing is turned off. However, 1/ I don’t know how to discern whether/when kexts are being installed, or 2/ who wrote the kexts already in /System/Library/Extensions/ from before, or 3/ if I miss an alert, how to determine after the fact.

So:
1/ Is there some way to get an alert, warning when a kext is being installed?
2/ Is there some way to determine which program installed the kexts already there?

Answer (score 1):

There is another option! If you get a Mac OS X developer certificate, you can sign the kext files you want yourself.

Comment: thanks for the answer! is there documentation on which kexts this **wouldn't** work for? Eg. would this work for TRIM Enabler on 3rd party SSDs? man, I hope you're right... seems too good to be true, given Trim Enabler's dev hasn't offered it as solution.

Comment: you are paying $99 for a dev cirtif. this will work with any kext.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. I updated the question to specify seeking a free solution.